# Struts logic tag equals not working

Tags: jsp, logic, struts

Very quick questions.
Could someone explain to me why this code does not work?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="logic"   uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" %>

<%
    int myValue= 2;
%>

myValue: <%=myValue%>
<br/>
<logic:equal name="myValue" value="2" scope="session">
    logic:equal works!
</logic:equal>
```

Even if I change myValue to a String is still doesn't work

Quite frustrating, cause I know it's going to be something obvious.

Thanks in advance

KS

---

Working example!

```
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" %>

<%
    request.setAttribute("myValue", 2);
%>

myValue - <%=request.getAttribute("myValue")%>]]

<br/>
<logic:equal name="myValue" value="2" scope="request">
    logic:equal works!
</logic:equal>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<logic:equal name="myValue" value="2" scope="session">
```

This tag looks for a session attribute named "myValue". Not for a local variable named "myValue".

The real question is: why are you using a tag library which is marked as deprecated in favor of the JSTL, this library being part of a framework which is officially abandoned?

Comment: Changed the scope to 'request' but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I specifically am not using a deprecated library in favor of the JSTL, but the company I work for, is. So I go with the tools handed to me.

Comment: Changing the scope to request will make it look for a request attribute named "myValue", not for a local variable named "myValue". Your scriptlet code should do: `request.setAttribute("myValue", 2)`. That will create a request attribute named "myValue".

Comment: Fantastic, cheers!  Edited my original question with the working version.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlet variables are not accessible to any scope. You can use them with scriptlet expressions but you can't use them in EL expressions. Read more about EL scopes [EL Variable Scopes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/PageDevGuide/html/s0203elvariablescopes01.html).

In the Struts applicationis possible to use JSTL along with Struts tags

```
<c:set var="myValue" value="2"/>
<c:if test="${myValue == 2}">
  if test works!
</c:if>
```