# how to compare null in jstl with variable?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

The value of y is null, but it always execute  otherwise part.   part. null is considered as not empty.

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty y}">
   value=""
  </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
 value="${y}"
</c:otherwise>
```

Comment: It's not null. My guess is that it is equal to the String "null".

Comment: try `logic:equal` and give value as `null`, if executed then what @JB Nizet said is right. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979470/struts-logic-tag-equals-not-working

Comment: i am not using struct

Comment: @RajanKumar Solved your problem ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua NO

Comment: Is `y` is string ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua thanks it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `y` is string write your code like this

```
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${y==null || y==''}">
          value=""
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
         value="${y}"
        </c:otherwise> 
    </c:choose>
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as `empty` will be doing for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185031/how-does-el-empty-operator-work-in-jsf