# How to verify value in struts

Tags: html, jsp, struts-1

I want to show or hide div: if error is empty (null) I want to show success div, and if error is not empty, the failed section should appear.

the problem is that the second div never appears.
Below is the code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<%
        String errorName="";
        String errorValue="";
        Map<String,String> errorMap = (Map<String,String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("erreurNameErreurValue");
        String addError = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("addError");
        errorName = errorMap.get("errorName");
        errorValue = errorMap.get("errorValue");
%>

<div class="centre">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <br>

    <div id="addResult">
        <br> </br>
        <c:if test="${empty addError}">
           <div id="failed">Erreur: <%= errorName%>
            <br> </br>
            <div id="resultatError">
                <% 
                    out.println(errorValue);
                %>
            </div>          

          </div>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${not empty errorValue}">
            <div id="success">
                Successful operation
                <br> </br>
            </div>  
        </c:if>
    <div>
<div>
```

the addError variable is filled in java class :

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("addError", error);
```

Comment: Look at the attribute name which differs `addError != errorAdd`.

Comment: you are right, but even I changed it doesn't work.

Comment: Of course https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980834/573032